# cant have two where statements in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have to search the database for certain results which are in one table but are not in a certain column in another table. my query below is what I have so far.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' AND NOT IN 
(SELECT friend FROM friends WHERE user='{$user_name}')";
```

as you can see I have the WHERE and then I declare the first item it has to search for. But then I add in AND so I am can search another table which is in the brackets.

What is the best way I can do this action without having to change my format to much?

*if anyone has any questions please post them below. So I can improve my question quality in the future please post below any ways that I can improve.*

Comment: Use `AND name NOT IN (SELECT ... )` , other than this your query looks fine.  What do you mean by `retaining the same results?`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I dont want the result to be different. sorry it wasn't explained well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the use of two `WHERE` clauses, it's that instead of writing:

```
... WHERE name LIKE '%xxx%' AND NOT IN (...) ...
```

you have to write:

```
... WHERE name LIKE '%xxx%' AND name NOT IN (...) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM users left join friends on users.name=friends.friend WHERE friends.friend IS NULL AND users.name LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%'"
```